# Twitter4j check if tweet is favorited by myself

Tags: java, api, twitter, javafx-2, twitter4j

I'm creating a Twitter app in Java and I need to check out if some particular tweet is in my favorites.

I read the doc, but did'nt find out what function does that kind of thing (hoping there is one).

Does somebody know ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Status` interface has the following method:

```
 /**
     * Test if the status is favorited
     *
     * @return true if favorited
     * @since Twitter4J 1.0.4
     */
    boolean isFavorited();
```

I made thw following example to show you how it works:

```
 ResponseList<Status> result = twitter.getFavorites();
        for (Status status : result)
        {
            System.out.println(status.getText());
            System.out.println(status.isFavorited());
        }
```

You can test also with ne following code:

```
 QueryResult result = twitter.search(new Query("Some term"));
        for (Status status : result.getTweets())
        {
            System.out.println(status.getText());
            System.out.println(status.getFavoriteCount());
            System.out.println(status.isFavorited());
        }
```

And you are going to see that some tweets has ***n*** number of favoriteCount but it is going to return false because it is not of your favorites.

Answer (score 0):

Oh thanks ! I was looking for a method in the FavoritesResources, forgot to check out Status' methods for this one.

Thank you, have a good day !

Edit : Seems that this method returns if a tweet has been favorited in general, not by me in particular. Back to start :)